# Is this a bug for BitmapFactory while decoding InputStream?

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I am using this code this time. I am wondering what is going wrong this time? I am using a code that load image from net. As you can see. But Image lose its quality as it decodes to Bitmap.(May be I am wrong).
You can check out this image.
[image]

I have  tried this

1. Get Image from URL and save that as .jpg image in drawable. then load image from resources. Its works perfectly this time. **BUT**
2. When I get Bitmap from URL instead of resources then It make make more BLUR you can check it from Above.

Its look like there may b a problem in BitmapFectory to de

```
public class MurgeActivity extends Activity {
String abcc = "http://c3.ac-images.myspacecdn.com/images02/84/s_48e1fd15504c49ed8fd008f8592f3082.jpg";
String abcd = "http://c1.ac-images.myspacecdn.com/images02/92/s_3bf09d34200c4423a2b8cb73f12675b8.jpg";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cus_image);
        ImageView img4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cus_image4);

        // Here I am getting image from net.
        Bitmap map = getImageFromWeb("http://c3.ac-images.myspacecdn.com/images02/84/s_48e1fd15504c49ed8fd008f8592f3082.jpg");

        // Here I am getting image from resources
        //Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.a1);

        Bitmap enlarge = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.enlarge_image_button);
        img1.setImageBitmap(map);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
        String items = combineArticleImage(encodedImage, enlarge);
        String imgTag = "<img width='100' src='data:image/png;base64," + items
                + "' align='left' style='padding-right:5px; padding-bottom:5px'/>";

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
        webView.loadData(imgTag, "text/html", "utf-8");

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(items, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        Drawable end = new BitmapDrawable(decodedByte);

        Drawable drb = Utils.combineSlidshowImages(new BitmapDrawable(map).getCurrent(), enlarge);
        img4.setImageDrawable(drb);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exeption", this.getClass().getSimpleName() + e.toString());
    } catch (Error error) {
        Log.e("Error", this.getClass().getSimpleName() + error.toString());
    }

}

public static String combineArticleImage(String baseImage, Bitmap frontImage) {

    String base64Image = null;
    byte[] imagesBytes = null;
    try {
        imagesBytes = Base64.decode(baseImage);

        if (imagesBytes != null) {


            Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagesBytes, 0, imagesBytes.length);

            Bitmap icon = frontImage;
            Bitmap finalImag = combineImages(map, icon);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            finalImag.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);

            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            base64Image = Base64.encodeBytes(b);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Combining Article Image");
    }
    return base64Image;
}

public static Bitmap getImageFromWeb(String imglink) {
    Bitmap bmpImage = null;
    try {

        URL imgURL = new URL(imglink);
        URLConnection conn = imgURL.openConnection();
        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        bis.close();
        is.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exeption", e.toString());
    } catch (Error error) {
        Log.e("Error", error.toString());
    }
    return bmpImage;
}

public static Bitmap combineImages(Bitmap backgroungImage, Bitmap frontImage) { // can
    Bitmap cs = null;
    try {

        cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroungImage.getWidth(), backgroungImage.getHeight(), backgroungImage
                .getConfig());

        Canvas comboImage = new Canvas(cs);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(backgroungImage, 0, 0, null);
        comboImage.drawBitmap(frontImage, backgroungImage.getWidth() - frontImage.getWidth(), backgroungImage
                .getHeight()
                - frontImage.getHeight(), null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Exception = " + e.toString());
    } catch (Error e) {
        Log.e("Error", "Message = " + e.toString());
    }
    return cs;
}
```

}
**main.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cus_image"
        android:src="@drawable/preview_unavailable"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cus_image4"
        android:src="@drawable/preview_unavailable"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
options.inScaled = false; 
Bitmap source = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activityName.getResources(), R.id.image, options);
```

Instead of:

```
 cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroungImage.getWidth(), backgroungImage.getHeight(), backgroungImage.getConfig());
```

try:

```
cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(backgroungImage.getWidth(), backgroungImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: I think that you will have to test the quality of the image stage by stage in your program. Your code is too long to analyze and some methods are not posted like Utils.combineSlidshowImages.

Comment: Hi, Thanks that work along with the 3 images for ldpi,mdpi,hdpi.

Answer (score 0):

When the image is in resources, then android adapt it with the right pixel density. When it comes from the web it doesn't know the density and tries with the current phone density.

Try to set a fixed density before decoding:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inDensity = android.util.DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM;
Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagesBytes, 0, imagesBytes.length);
```

bazinga

Comment: Thanks for your time. But Its still giving me same result?